# Edit distance library in Java supporting user cost functions

Tags: java, levenshtein-distance

There are quite a few edit distance implementations for Java. However, they mostly implement specifically Levenshtein distance, i.e. one where cost of any replacement is 2, any insertion: 1, and any deletion: 1. Is there an existing library where I can supply a different cost for edits, so that e.g. replacing "m" by "n" costs less than replacing "m" by "a"?